# Why ionic app throws certificate error on iOS since iOS 14?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

Since iOS 14 a my app fails all requests, e.g. auth-request fails due to some kind of certificate error:

```
The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “some.auth.domain.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://some.auth.domain.com/index.php/auth due to access control checks.
```

Browser, Android versions as well as older iOS devices have no problem running the app.
I'm using ionic 6.11.11

Comment: I don't see answer but seems related to : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655074

Comment: Yeah, seems like a similar issue, but can't find a solution in that forum.